# Sending Mouse and keyboard inputs from server to client over socket in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have my desktop stream working the server can see the client desktop, what I basically do is grab screenshots from client and send it to server continuously and displaying it using `cv2.imshow()`.
Now I want a way to send mouse and keyboards inputs from server to the client so that it can control the client remotely. I know `pyautogui` module could be used to simulate moving, click and dragging mouse as well as pressing keys.
One way I thought is to send the coordinates in fractions of the resolution.

**Example:**
If your picturebox is 800x600 and you click at location (200, 300), send (0.25, 0.5).
On the other machine, you receive (0.25, 0.5) and you multiply them by the resolution. On a 1024x768, you move the mouse pointer to location (256, 384).

But I need a method to get the mouse and keyboard input from the `opencv` window and send it to the client over the socket and then simulate it on client side.

Any other method instead of using `opencv` to display the frames on server would be accepted as well, as long as I am able to work with keyboard and mouse inputs and improves the performance.

**Note**: I am also not able to get the screenshot of the UAC prompt using `Imagegrab.grab()` even if I run the script as an administrator I don't know why
this is happening.

Below is my code for client and server exceptions which are not being handled as I am just trying out that the things work.

Any **suggestions** to make my stream faster are welcomed as well :)

server.py:

```
import socket
import struct
import cv2
import numpy

host = "192.168.0.5"
port = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) #create socket
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
c , addr = s.accept()
print("Connection recieved from {}".format(addr))

cv2.namedWindow("Remote Desktop",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
while True:
    bs = c.recv(8)
    (length,) = struct.unpack(">Q",bs) # get length of image
    data = b''
    while(len(data)<length):  # get image data
        recv_data = length - len(data)
        if(recv_data>4096):
            data += c.recv(4096)
        else:
            data += c.recv(recv_data)

    with open("demo.jpg","wb") as f:
        d = f.write(data)
        #print(d)
    img = cv2.imread("demo.jpg")
    cv2.imshow("Remote Desktop",img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
s.close()
```

Here is my client.py:

```
import socket
import struct
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

host = "192.168.0.5"
port = 4444
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) #create socket
s.connect((host,port)) #connect to server
print("Connection Established")
time.sleep(5)

while True:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img.save("demo.jpg","JPEG")
        with open("demo.jpg","rb") as f:
            data = f.read()    # read the image
            s.sendall(struct.pack(">Q",len(data))) #send the length of image in bytes
            s.sendall(data)     # send the data

s.close()
```

So how can I send mouse and keyboard inputs effectively over socket in `python`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you out....Make it according to you need.

```
import threading
import mouse
import keyboard

mouse_events = []


mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard.start_recording()

keyboard.wait("*")

mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording()

#Keyboard threadings:

k_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :keyboard.play(keyboard_events))
k_thread.start()

#Mouse threadings:

m_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :mouse.play(mouse_events))
m_thread.start()

#waiting for both threadings to be completed

k_thread.join() 
m_thread.join()
```